# App which are not using media projection api method to take screenshot cam bypass screnshot shot blocker library/software?

Tags: java, android, security, sdk, screenshot

As i have read that "screenshot Blocker" library intercept the media projection api to check if screenshot is being taken.

What if a software uses another method to take screenshot?

Will it work?
Can it bypass screnshot blocker

It is a vulnerability?

I m trying to find such apps that don't use media projection for screenshot.